# Обработка маршрута

Tags: php, yii2

Каким образом лучше решить такую задачу:

Вот маршрут в формате обычного ЧПУ:

```
htt://domain.com/user/list
```

Где `user` - контроллер, а `list` - действие

Необходимо в начале каждого маршрута указывать id сущности, с которой происходит работа, вот так:

```
htt://domain.com/25/user/list
```

И при этом нужно, чтобы создавались контроллеры и вызывались действия по обычному сценарию, если id этой сущности (`25`) существует в БД.

**UPDATE**

`25` - это ID проекта, а не юзера. И маршрут просит дать всех юзеров проекта с ID=25.

Другой пример:

```
htt://domain.com/ru/user/list
```

Или:

```
htt://domain.com/en/user/list
```

Comment: `htt://domain.com/25/user/list` - так никто не делает. только извращенцы.... `http://domain.com/user/25` - так делают и `http://domain.com/users/page/25` делают

Comment: @АлексейШиманский под сущностью я понимал вовсе не самого юзера. Данный маршрут можно объяснить так: дай мне список всех юзеров проекта 25

Answer (score 0):

В конфиге сайта (backend || frontend)/main.php указываешь

```
'urlManager' => [
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => [
           '<locale:\w+>/<controller>/<action>' =>  '<controller>/<action>'
        ],
    ],
```

При запросах на http://domain.com/en/user/list/ будет отправлять по сути на

http://domain.com?r=user&action=list&locale=en

В качестве `<locale:\w+>` можешь писать любое название например `<id:\d+>`, это будет переменной для get запросов. \w+ это означает что любые символы `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` а `\d+` это цифры [0-9]

Comment: И тогда в каждом действии каждого контроллера мне придется писать один и тот же код, определяющий настройки языка приложения... Не говоря о том, что теперь все мои rules будут иметь в начале строку <locale: \w+> Не очень комильфо...

Comment: А ты можешь сделать BaseController настроить нужные вещи, и наследовать все свои контроллеры от него и никакого дублирования :) на счет всех остальных rules => тут зависит от того как расположишь это правило, в начале все общие правила - потом все специфичные и все будет гуд. Но у тебя у самого специфичные требования) пересмотри роутинг.

Comment: Но ведь обработка locale переменной должна быть в каждом action-е, верно? Тогда как мне поможет создание BaseController, если это должно происходить в каждом методе?

Comment: В любом случае спасибо за помощь, но пока вопрос остается открытым, ибо это не самое верное решение с точки зрения архитектуры приложения

Comment: Для мультиязычности существуют другие - более лучшие подходы, либо попробовать UrlManager допилить как здесь: https://habrahabr.ru/post/226931/ 
ну а сущности свои подсунуть перед названием контроллера можно всегда.

Comment: Ссылка на статью помогла решить проблему, большое спасибо! Если вы переделаете ответ с кратким описанием сути и ссылкой на эту статью, я зачту ответ